# How to skip the conversion process after uploading file to vimeo?

Tags: api, video, vimeo

I think this a though in-depth question… I haven't found any posts, FAQ, help files or Google results about is.

I'm building an app that uses vimeo API to upload and steam video.
The problem that vimeo conversion time is too long. 
Is there any way to skip vimeo's conversion process (especially when using the API to upload)?

Is it possible to upload a video converted to the exact final file that vimeo will eventually stream and skip the long conversion process?

I read the Compression Guidelines (https://vimeo.com/help/compression) and saw that "Adobe Media Encoder" doesn't support all the specifications (the vimeo presets, aren't aligned with the guidelines)

So, any help –

1. Is it possible to skip conversion?
2. If yes, how?
3. If no, any recommended video converter software that can convert according to vimeo compression guidelines to save on conversion time…?

Thanks,
Help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Either way, I think I'd be asking Vimeo, not SO.

Comment: Keep in mind that their conversion process may be transcoding to a dozen different formats to deal with different browsers, codecs, etc. that users use. I don't know that for a fact, but it would make sense. And they do a really good job of making their videos available on many platforms. (Unlike YouTube where half their content is just unavailable on most devices.)

Answer (score 1):

According to Vimeo staff [Mark](https://vimeo.com/mark)'s [post](https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:107111):

> We re-encode all videos that are uploaded **without exception**.

But as stated by [user1118321](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1118321/user1118321), they need to encode at least a low-res (non-HD) version of your movie, in case you upload a HD video, of course.